# nvm doesnt change node version (I use Ubuntu 16.04 x64)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

I've installed nvm and used following commands : `nvm install 5.0` and `nvm use 5.0`. but when I tap `nodejs -v`, it says that i have `v4.2.6` - same one as I had before. How can i get 5.0?

Comment: What is the output of `which nodejs`?

Comment: `nvm` may install Node under the default binary name – `node -v`. Though, on Ubuntu, that name may already refer to another programs. Check with `which -a node` if it's alone in using the name.

Comment: @slugonamission  `/usr/bin/nodejs`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/node`
 `/usr/bin/node`

Comment: @Max The file under `/home/me/.nvm/` is what you want with `nvm`. And, it did install it as `node` instead of `nodejs`. So, use `node` with `nvm` and `nodejs` for the system-installed version retrieved through `apt-get`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski aah, i see. thank You much.